# jquery .scrollTo in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project in which i have to display certain data row. I am using table for that purpose.

Here's a [demo of table](http://nitinkabra.com/table)

Now the problem is whenever i change the selection of row or scroll the current row, it goes hiding up or down . How do I fix the scroll so that it shows the current row ?

How can I implement .scrollTo()

Comment: do you want to scroll your table to current selected row via programmatically?

Comment: yes.. i want to scroll the div such that the current row in visible..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollIntoView()` which is used to scroll the element to visible in a page.
it works based on DOM element. Add `selectedRow` class to selected `tr` and use that 
DOM element.

```
 $('table').find('tr.selectedRow')[0].scrollIntoView()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  , but i did not test the code .

```
var pos_top = 0 ;

jQuery('tr').click(function(){

    var element_pos = jQuery(this).position();
    pos_top = element_pos.top;
});


jQuery('.change_but').click(function(){

    jQuery('tbody').scrollTop(pos_top);   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't work for TR element (I don't know why), but works for TD. Use:
$('table').find('tr.selectedRow').find('TD').get(0).scrollIntoView();